# Spring Boot: how do I create a self-contained executable jar?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, executable-jar

I am new with Spring Boot and failed to create a self-contained executable jar. The Maven created jar fails to detect the Beans that it needs at runtime.

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

I checked the factory if an implementation of the factory is in the jar which is the case. I also carefully checked other posts and made sure that the Spring Boot annotation is in place. It includes the @ComponentScan and others.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InitService {
```

I assume that my pom has the dependencies correctly set, because the application runs well when I start it from my Eclipse project.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>de.newbe.create.InitService</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So now I challenge the community and hope for your valuable expertise and support. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The maven-assembly-plugin appears to be the wrong choice for Spring Boot will not be able to detect the jars. Instead as Mathias pointed out one needs the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 7):

I would try to setup the project like here (see pom.xml) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

A simple `mvn package` should be enough to generate the jar.

See here for details - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin